# How to examine url and emit routing with page.js

Tags: page.js

Is it possible to emit routing on the current URL, i.e., get page.js to call the respective callback on the current path?

The use case for this is if a user is signing in/out of my app, I want page.js to then route on the current path, since the current route may show different views based on authentication status.

I was using the Riot.js router and just switched over to leverage some page.js features, but page.js seems to be missing this core feature that Riot.js has (see [here](http://riotjs.com/api/route/#routeexec)).

p.s. Currently my workaround is simply `location.reload()`, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause Page to route to any arbitrary URL by simply calling page with the URL.

So in your case, you might try:

```
page( location.pathname );
```

Or if you have some other method of maintaining a method of what route you're currently on:

```
page( someStorageMechanism.currentRoute );
```

However, `location.reload();` is unlikely to *ever* break. I would personally consider this ideal, rather than less than ideal. Why not use the native browser behaviors?

Comment: In retrospect I should have thought to use location :) The reason why I didn't want reload is b/c I like to maintain app state as well as prevent the latency from a refresh.

Comment: Keep in mind that - subject to browser-by-browser differences - `location.reload()` (note no parameter) could reload [right from the browser cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), therefore maintaining state, etc. There's certainly no guarantee thanks to the considerable leeway browser vendors might have here, but it could be something worth doing some functional testing on.